# FreeType text upside down

Tags: c++, opengl

I am working on a OpenGL and C++ project (a little 2D game) and i am currently implementing font rendering. I am using FreeType to handle font file and glyphs and i have successfully (kinda) rendered the glyphs onto the screen. However the glyphs appear to be upside down and my sprites are the correct way up.

Texture coords for a sprite (these go into a vbo then into a vao)

```
vec2 uv_topLeft(0.0, 0.0);
vec2 uv_topRight(1.0, 0.0);
vec2 uv_bottomRight(1.0, 1.0);
vec2 uv_bottomLeft(0.0, 1.0);

uvs.push_back(uv_topLeft);
uvs.push_back(uv_bottomLeft);
uvs.push_back(uv_bottomRight);
uvs.push_back(uv_bottomRight);
uvs.push_back(uv_topRight);
uvs.push_back(uv_topLeft);
```

I just have a projection matrix whcih i use to transform the vertex positions to NDC coordinates.

Projection matrix:(WINDOW_WIDTH=960, WINDOW_HEIGHT=640)
    glm::ortho(0.0, (double)WINDOW_WIDTH, 0.0, (double)WINDOW_HEIGHT);

[image: Picture of game with sprites and text]

I saw somewhere that openGL and Freetype use different coordinate systems is that true?

Comment: Edit in a [mcve].  You've given *zero* indication how you're uploading the FreeType glyphs to OpenGL or how your texture coordinates and matrix transforms are set up.

Answer (score 1):

> However the glyphs appear to be upside down and my sprites are the correct way up.

THis is because you are using different conventions than freetype. Classical OpenGL uses (0,0) as the *bottom* left origin of the texture, while you are using this as top-left.

So if you want to be able to use the same code to generate the vertex data for both freetype glyuphs and your sprites, you have to decide on one convention.

Note that these conventions mean nothing, (0,0) is just the first texel that you feed into `glTexImage`, if that is to be top or bottom is completely up to you.

Comment: i have changed to uvs so that 0,0 is the bottom left and the top right is 1,1 and i add them in the order that i add the vertices but know the glyphs are the correct way up but the sprites are upside down. As the two coordinate systems/conventions are different won't the glyphs and sprites always be flipped opposite.

Comment: Well, flipping the convention implies flipping the image data. Just trying to fix with via the vertex data is never going to work, unless you generate different data for glyphs and sprites.

Comment: I ended up having another go at trying to fix the problem once i read one of the answer that said they use different coordinate conventions and just generated different uvs for the glyphs and it works fine, i knew the problem and had a idea how to fix it but i wanted to see if there was a better, more elegant way that i could go about solving it. Thank you anyways!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just generating different uvs for the glyphs so that they got applied to the quad the correct way up.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same problem, after some research

I think this is because the memory layout used by Freetype is not the same as the memory layout of common image formats.

So there are only two solutions:

1. Apply different uv coordinates for characters.
2. Flip the memory of the character.

**more details**

Use the following function to print the freetype bitmap.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

...

void print_FT_Bitmap(FT_Face face){
    int r = face->glyph->bitmap.rows;
    int w = face->glyph->bitmap.width;

    for(int i = 0; i<r*w; i++){
        cout<< setw(2) << setfill('0') << hex << int(face->glyph->bitmap.buffer[i]);

        if(i!=0 && (i+1)%w==0){
            cout << "\n";
        }
    }
}

...
```

You'll see an exact character image whose memory starts at the top left, which doesn't coincide with the image's origin.
(The origin of this character image should be at the bottom left.)

For example the output of "W" is like this:

```
i=0 is here
↓
49fff704000000000090ffbb000000000000c9ff51
14ffff2c0000000000cffff5060000000003f6ff1d
00dfff5c0000000010fdffff3b000000002cffea00
00aaff8d000000004dffb0ff7b000000005effb600
0075ffbd000000008dff44ffbb0000000090ff8300
0040ffee00000000ccf001e6f606000000c2ff4f00
000dfdff1f00000efcbb00b1ff3b000001f2ff1c00
0000d6ff4f00004aff830078ff7b000025ffe90000
0000a1ff8000008aff450039ffbb000057ffb40000
00006bffb10000c9fb0c0005f5f6060089ff810000
000036ffdf0008fac9000000bcff3500b5ff4d0000
000007fafe0d38ff8c0000007dff6b00deff1a0000
000000ccff396eff4e0000003effa109fee7000000
00000097ff67a4fe1200000007f7d731ffb3000000
00000062ff94dad30000000000c0fe6aff7f000000
0000002dffd7ff95000000000081ffceff4c000000
00000003f4ffff57000000000042ffffff19000000
00000000c2ffff1a000000000009f9ffe500000000
↑
Image origin is here
```

On the other hand, if you use any kind of hex viewer to view the memory of an uncompressed picture (such as a BMP picture), you will find that the start of memory is consistent with the Image origin.

Answer (score -1):

Those fonts are actually textures which are painted on a rectangle, which consists of two triangles. You need to rotate them by matrix multiplication. That's elementary OpenGL work you should start learning.

Comment: Doing this would flip the gyphs around but it would also flip my sprites around so it doesn't accomplish anything as i use the same render/shader pipeline to render sprites even if its a glyph, as you said its just a texture on a piece of geometry

Comment: I could do this but it would be a very hacky, un-elegant way of achieving what i want. I an reluctant to do this method as in a video that i watched they also use the same technology as me (opengl, c+, freetype) and their gylphs were the correct way up. (video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rsdc6I80aFQ&t=2168s)